# Error building Android app in release mode, in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-keystore

I'm trying to sign my android app in release mode, in Android Studio.

I followed [this official guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html). So I have created the keystore and a private key. Then I tried to Generate the Signed APK, from **Build -> Generate Signed API Key**. But the build fails, with the following error:

```
:app:packageRelease FAILED
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageRelease'.
> File 'C:\Documents\myapp\android.jks' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.
```

I have also checked the build.gradle configuration. And I have found this:

```
   signingConfigs {
        releaseConfig {
            keyAlias 'xxxxxxxxxx'
            keyPassword 'xxxxxxxxx'
            storeFile file('C:\Documents\myapp\android.jks')
            storePassword 'xxxxxxxxx'
        }
    }
```

but in the same gradle file I have this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
        }
    }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: file `android.jks` exists in C:\Documents\myapp\?

Comment: of course, @PetrDuchek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, simply moving the keystore inside the base path of my android project.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\` by `\\`:

```
storeFile file('C:\\Documents\\myapp\\android.jks')
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the `keystore` file in `app` folder of that project, and replace with following

```
storeFile file('android.jks')
```